# Code only binds to events in developer console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pop-up that has a `.close` class which is basically just an `X` plus some extra spacing. My problem is, I can't get the click event to work when it's in my code, however, if I paste it into Google's dev tools console, it works as expected...

The culprit...

```
$('.modal').bind(touchClick, 'close', function(e) {
    $('.modal.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.modal.b').removeClass('b');
    $('.modal.c').removeClass('c');
    $('.modal.d').removeClass('d');
    $('.modal.e').removeClass('e');
    $('.modal .content').html('');
});
```

The setup...

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="close">
            <div class="x"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Google is a rather massive corporation, did you mean Chrome? (they actually make some other browsers, too). That said, can you turn this into a jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com example, so we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: The problem is *probably* in not using `jQuery.ready` and attempting to bind to elements that do not exist yet.. however, without a *minimal* reproduction test-case on http://jsfiddle.net or similar, I am closing due to only providing enough information for conjecture.

Comment: Was the modal created on page load or on pop up? When is the handler for close ran? You need to provide more information/code

Answer (score 1):

Is your script above your html?

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.modal').bind(touchClick, 'close', function(e) {
        $('.modal.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.modal.b').removeClass('b');
        $('.modal.c').removeClass('c');
        $('.modal.d').removeClass('d');
        $('.modal.e').removeClass('e');
        $('.modal .content').html('');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .modal node is in the DOM before you execute your code.

The code attaches a click handler to .modal. If it isn't in the dom, there is nothing to attach it to.

If the modal is being injected into the DOM, make the click handler attach to the body instead.

```
$('body').bind(touchClick, '.modal .close', function (e) {
  ...
});
```

Note that I added a . to close to make it a class...

Comment: Note that `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.` - from the [jQuery docs for bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). bind() should only be used if you're using jQuery 1.6 and lower.